# Por qué no entra a la linea 7 de mi código

Tags: jquery

Este es mi codigo,  lo que estoy haciendo es encontrar el dato DNI en BD y  al presinar boton que me llena los campos faltantes pero siempre cuando existe el dato que estoy ingresando.

```
function LlenarDatos() {
    var URL = window.location.pathname;
    URL = URL.split("/");
    var IdComBlo = URL[URL.length - 1];

   $('#btn1').click(function () {
   alert("entro1");
        $('#txtDNI').on('input', function (e) {
            alert("entro2");
        const dni = $(this).val();
        const nacionalidad = $('#cboNacionalidad').val();
        alert("entrooo333333");
        $.ajax(
             {
                 url: '/comprarbloqueo/GuardarDatosPriCliente?combloId=' + IdComBlo,
                 type: 'POST',
                 //data: "",
                 data: { dni, nacionalidad },
                 contentType: 'json; charset=utf-8',
                 success: function (data) {
                 }
             })
          .done(function (data) {
             if (!data) { return; }
             $(data).each(function (i, row) {
                 $("#txtDNI").focusout(function () {
                 $('#txtNombre').val(row.CLI_Nombre);
                 $('#txtApellidoPa').val(row.CLI_ApellidoPa);
                 $('#txtApellidoMa').val(row.CLI_ApellidoMa);
                 $('#txtTelefono').val(row.CLI_Telefono);
                 $('#txtPasaporte').val(row.CLI_Pasaporte);
                 $('#txtEmail').val(row.CLI_Email);
             });
                 //remueves el listener una vez encontrado un riesgo
             $(this).off('input');
         });
       });
    });
 });
}
```

Comment: Sugiero que pongas el código más legible y organizado. Bastante con seleccionar todo el código requerido y pulsando sobre los corchetes {} "Ejemplo de código <pre>...".

Comment: Habría sido útil que indiques cuál es esa línea 7, supongo que esta o alguna de las que le siguen: `$('#btn1').click(function () {`. Puede que, en el HTML no tengas ningún elemento con `id="#btn1"` o que no estés agregando la librería de jQuery en el código. Cuando depures código, mira siempre la consola de Javascript, que se encuentra en las opciones de Desarrollador de tu navegador.

Comment: $('#txtDNI').on('input', function (e) {
a esta linea no entra

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el HTML? ¿Qué recoges en el elemento con id `txtDNI` un archivo?

Comment: <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-8" style="left:40px">
<label class="control-label"><b>Nro.Documento ó Identidad</b></label>       
<input class="form-control" type="text"  id="txtDNI"  onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" maxlength="8">
</div>
</div>
<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="left:50px;top:20px">Buscar</button>

Comment: Dices que presionas en `#btn1` y luego de eso modificas el contenido del DNI y luego de salirte del elemento no ocurre nada?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tú tienes el código encerrado dentro de una función `LlenarDatos` que nunca es invocada. Además, dentro del click del botón agregas un listener para el input. Generalmente son funciones diferentes para procedimientos diferentes... No comprendo por qué estás concibiendo tus funciones como si estuviesen anidadas, dependiendo unas de otras.

Aparte de eso, (creo), que el código es mejorable:

- He encerrado todo dentro de `function`, el sustituto de `document.ready`. Hay que usarlo siempre que se vaya  a manipular elementos del DOM.
- Observa los listeners que he agregado a tu input dni. Supongo que te interesa evaluar algo cuando se escriba en ese input o cambie de valor. Si no es así, lo puedes cambiar.
- Tu petición Ajax usa dos funciones que hace casi lo mismo. Me refiero a `success` y a `done`. Una sola es suficiente... y para mejorarla, debería tener al menos un manejo con `fail`, en el caso de algún fallo en el código. Y propongo que te decidas por `done`, ya que `success` es obsoleto desde jQuery 3. En ese sentido [revisa la doc de jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Casi al final del enlace hay un ejemplo idóneo de petición con `done` y con `fail`.

```js
$(function() {

    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
        var dni=$("#txtDNI").val();
        alert('El input DNI tiene el valor: '+dni);
        /*Aquí se podrían recoger los datos y hacer la petición Ajax*/
        /*Quizá si usas un elemento <form> sería más fácil recoger los datos*/
        /*usando serialize()*/

    });


    $('#txtDNI').on('change paste keyup', function() {
        const dni = $(this).val();
        const nacionalidad = $('#cboNacionalidad').val();
        console.log('El DNI  tiene el valor: '+dni);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-8" style="left:40px"> <label class="control-label"><b>Nro.Documento ó Identidad</b></label> <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtDNI" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" maxlength="8"> </div>
</div> <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="left:50px;top:20px">Buscar</button>
```